# Using the iphlpapi library in QT

Tags: qt

I am trying to use the `GetAdaptersAddresses` function
In QT for this I tried to import the `iphlpapi.h`

This is my code:

```
#include <iphlpapi.h>
int check_mac(char * mac_vendor) 
{
    unsigned long alist_size = 0, ret;

    ret = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC,0,0,0,&alist_size); 

}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
error: C3861: 'GetAdaptersAddresses': identifier not found
```

This is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ooTptro
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp 

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h 

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui


LIBS += Advapi32.lib
#LIBS += IPHLPAPI.lib
win32:LIBS += -lIPHLPAPI
```

Does anyone know why QT does not recognize the function and the include even though I have added both the include and the .pro file?

Comment: Not a Qt issue for sure but preprocessor/compilation. Likely the function is disabled by ifdef's in the header file. Some definitions may need to be included. Try the way MS includes it in examples: `#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>` and see if that helps or open iphlpapi.h and find how exactly the function GetAdaptersAddresses is enabled.

Comment: Not sure if you have a special reason for using the windows-only iphlpapi.h, but Qt includes the [QNetworkInterface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html#allInterfaces) and related classes, which can easily be used to get all network adapters in a system, get MAC addresses, and as a bonus work on all platforms.

Comment: @docsteer Ever tried to get actual MAC address with QNetworkInterface?

Comment: i have to use `GetAdaptersAddresses` so solutions of using  `QNetworkInterface` are ofcoarse possible but don't solve this problem